# Not getting data using fetch Api

Tags: reactjs, api

I am using open source Api link and using it in React. I am not able to get data in the browser. What am I doing wrong? Here I trying to get Country name and calling code.

```
export default class Api extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            country:[]
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(
            result=>{
                console.log(result);
                console.warn(result);
                // this.setState({country:result});
                console.log("i am in console");
            }
        )
    }
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
            <h1 className="text-center"> Api</h1>
            <h2> country details</h2>
            <div>{this.state.country.map(countries => { 
               <div key={countries.name}>
                   {/* <div {countries.name}></div> */}
                   <div>{countries.alpha3Code}</div>
                   <div>{countries.callingCodes}</div>
               </div>
                }
                )}</div>
            </div>
        );
    
}
}
```

Comment: Please add any form of error log or console output you're getting, thanks!

Comment: Data is getting in console but not in Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something from that map function like so:

```
           <div>{this.state.country.map(countries =>  
               <div key={countries.name}>
                   <div> {countries.name}></div>
                   <div>{countries.alpha3Code}</div>
                   <div>{countries.callingCodes}</div>
               </div>                
                )}</div>
            </div>
```

Notice the absence of `{` in `countries =>` , which is a substitute for the `return` statement.

Apart from that, just uncomment your state setting line `// this.setState({country:result});` and you're good to go.

And here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-architecture-wdrss?file=/src/App.js) just in case.